# Awaited method returns empty collection unless I use breakpoint inside

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm writting a program in C# which will recive messages from other programs, it needs to to read messages and in some cases prepare and send responses.
I wrote this method to handle a single message, and I call it asynchronously (using `await`) or synchronously depending on its type.

```
public async void HandleMessage(Message message)
{
    IEnumerable<Tuple<Message, ulong>> responses;
    try
    {
        if (!_communicateTypesToHandleSync.Contains(message.GetType()))
        {
             responses = await Task.Run(() => _requestHandler.HandleRequest(message));
        }
        else
        {
            responses = _requestHandler.HandleRequest(message);
        }
        foreach (var response in responses)
        {
            CSMessageHandler.AddMessageToSend(response.Item1, response.Item2);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Error while handling message");
    }
}
```

The problem is that calling `HandleRequest` using await seems to always return an empty collection (I checked it with a conditional breakpoint).
I tried to debug it and when I finally found out what was going on I set a breakpoint at the end of `HandleRequest` that will stop only if collection is not empty. On this breakpoint code execution stopped and when I stepped out from `HandleRequest` even in `HandleMessage` I had not-empty `responses`.

Comment: It is a bad code practice to await a synchronous method; also stop using Task.Run in this context. Look at [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Async-Library-Methods-Shouldn-t-Lie) excelent video.

Comment: @JeroenHeier how about summarize it in a few sentences. 16 mins are too long for me...

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. What kind of application is this? What's de calling code?

Comment: I really doubt you are calling a void method using await. Post more complete code.

Answer (score 2):

HandleMessage should either return a **`Task`** if void or 
**`Task<IEnumerable<Tuple<Message, ulong>>>`** if you would like to return `IEnumerable<Tuple<Message, ulong>>`.  You should not use void unless it's a delegate.

Your code should be

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Tuple<Message, ulong>>> HandleMessage(Message message)
{
    IEnumerable<Tuple<Message, ulong>> responses;
    try
    {
        if (!_communicateTypesToHandleSync.Contains(message.GetType()))
        {
             responses = await Task.Run(() => _requestHandler.HandleRequest(message));
        }
        else
        {
            responses = _requestHandler.HandleRequest(message);
        }
        foreach (var response in responses)
        {
            CSMessageHandler.AddMessageToSend(response.Item1, response.Item2);
        }

        return responses;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.Error(ex, "Error while handling message");
    }
}
```

Your call should be

```
await HandleMessage(Message message);
```

Since the method is a void, when you make a call to **HandleMessage**, it's not being awaited.  The method is entered on 1 thread, then you do a **Task.Run** to start another thread.  When a second thread is started, thread 1 is freed and continues to run on a calling function.

For example:

```
//do one thing
HandleMessage(message);
//Do other work
```

The thread 1 would continue to do the other work when it is freed up when **Task.Run** spins up another thread.